# Anführungszeichenmissbrauch

Tags: punctuation, quotes

Ohne es definitiv zu wissen, behaupte ich, zur Verdeutlichung meiner Frage, dass es zwei legitime Verwendungen von Anführungsstrichen gibt, neben der Markierung direkter Rede:  <strike>Ironieverdeutlichung</strike> Ausdruck von Hohn und die Hervorhebung der Wörter, die grammatisch nicht an die Stelle passen, sondern auf einer anderen Ebene spielen, als der Rest des Satzes.

Beispiel 1:

```
Frau von der Leyen verkauft den "Rückgang" der Arbeitslosigkeit als ihr Verdienst.
```

Beispiel 2:

```
Gern teile ich Dir mit, dass man das "gern" auch an den Satzanfang ziehen kann.
```

Beides dient der Erleichterung des Lesens. Dagegen werden unbekannte Fremdworte, Eigen- und Markennamen gewöhnlich nicht mit Anführungsstrichen versehen:

Beispiel 3:

```
Die Hirokuwah beten zu ihren Göttern Bru und Fiililii.
```

Beispiel 4:

```
Wir haben es mit unserer Sony aufgezeichnet.
```

Ist das richtig oder gibt es neben direkter Rede noch einen weiteren Grund Anführungszeichen zu setzen? Dies unter der Annahme, dass alternative Auszeichnungsmöglichkeiten wie *kursive Schreibung* etc. nicht zur Verfügung stehen.

Mehr für die Kommentare oder nebenbei: andere, typische Beispiele für die fehlerhafte Verwendung von Anführungszeichen.

**Update:**

Auf Belleletres fand ich jetzt ein Videotutorial 
http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/gansefusschen-anfuhrungszeichen.php, (75 min) welches ausführlich diese Zeichensetzung behandelt. Eine Selbstantwort mache ich nicht daraus, da es zu viele Informationen sind, um sie alle darzustellen. In den wesentlichsten Punkten stimmt es mit dem hier gesagten m.E. überein. Die Faustregel lautet: Sparsamkeit oder direkte Rede.

Zwei Punkte möchte ich jedoch herausgreifen.

1. Im Gegensatz zu mir bestreitet der Autor, dass Ironie durch Anführungsstriche ausdrückbar sei, denn Ironie versteckt die Kritik, während Anführungsstriche sie ausstellt. Mit Anführungsstrichen wird es daher zu Hohn. Diese Argumentation finde ich unmittelbar einleuchtend.
2. In TehMacDawgs erstem Beispiel erscheint das Magazin Spiegel in Anführungsstrichen. Dies schildert der Videotutor als gängige Praxis, aber beschränkt auf den Journalismus als Urheber des Textes selbst.

**Update 2:**

Ich fand heute einen Blogbeitrag, in dem der Autor berichtet, dass Victor Klemperer in einem Buch über die Sprache des dritten Reiches eine exzessive Anführungszeichennutzung feststellt und kritisiert: [Ironische Anfuhrungszeichen Distanzierungsmittel der Feigen](http://sciencefiles.org/2014/04/30/ironische-anfuhrungszeichen-distanzierungsmittel-der-feigen/). Er spricht mir aus der Seele.

Comment: Zu den verbesserungswürdigen Teilen: In Beisp. 1 muss es heißen "als *ihren* Verdienst". In Beisp. 2 wäre mir der Ausdruck *setzen* geläufiger als *ziehen*. Der erste Absatz der Frage ist etwas schwer lesbar, vor allem wegen dem komplizierten Satzbau und der leicht ungewöhnlichen Ausdrucksweise.

Comment: @TehMacDawg: Nach Rücksprache mit meinem [persönlichen Lektorat](http://textundsinn.wordpress.com) bin ich bestätigt, aber aus anderem Grund als gedacht: 'Verdienst' ist sächlich, 'das Verdienst' - daraus folgt: 'ihr Verdienst', wie 'als ihr Kind', 'als ihr Marzipan' - dagegen 'der Nikolaus' -> 'als ihren Nikolaus'.

Comment: @userunknown Stimmt... ist aber ein fieser Trick, [schließlich gibt es Verdienst auch im Maskulinum](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/verdienst) ;)

Comment: @Clemens: Fieser Trick wäre es, wenn ich die Falle absichtlich aufgestellt hätte, ahnend dass da jmd. reingeht. Ich hab's aber arglos richtig formuliert, ohne die Regel benennen zu können. :)

Comment: @userunknown Manchmal ist es ja die Sprache selbst, die einem Stolperfallen legt.

Comment: @userunknown: Ahrg! Toll – der Verdienst und das Verdienst. Ist wohl eines dieser kleinen Klassiker, an die man sich eigentlich erinnern sollte.

Comment: @TehMacDawg Wohl eher eine*r* dieser Klassiker ;)

Answer (score 8):

Die Beispiele von dir sind alle korrekt. Darüber hinaus gibt es noch weitere Anwendungsfälle:

1) Überschriften, Werktitel (etwa von Büchern und Theaterstücken), Namen von Zeitungen und dergleichen:

```
Sie las den Artikel „Staatliche Schulen testen Einheitskleidung“ im „Spiegel“.
```

2) Sprichwörter, Äußerungen und dergleichen, zu denen man kommentierend Stellung nehmen will:

```
Das Sprichwort „Eile mit Weile“ hört man oft. 
„Aller Anfang ist schwer“ ist nicht immer ein hilfreicher Spruch.
```

Die aktuellen in Deutschland amtlichen Rechtschreib- und Zeichensetzungsregeln werden vom *Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung* als PDF-Datei zum Download angeboten (Regeln 2006): http://www.rechtschreibrat.com (Die Satzbeispiele habe ich alle daraus geklaut.)

Ich würde noch auf den korrekten typografischen Standard hinweisen, der bei formellen Texten und Veröffentlichungen eingehalten werden sollte (bei Handschreibung jedoch immer): Anders als z.B. im Englischen gilt die Regel *99 unten … 66 oben*, bei Anführungszeichen innerhalb von Anführungszeichen entsprechend als *halbe Anführungszeichen*: *9 unten … 6 oben*.

```
„Das war ein Satz aus Bölls ,Wo warst du, Adam?‘, 
den viele nicht kennen“, sagte er.
```

Alternativ können auch umgekehrte französische Anführungszeichen benutzt werden, siehe auch http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemets

```
»Das war ein Satz aus Bölls ›Wo warst du, Adam?‹, 
den viele nicht kennen«, sagte er.
```

Eine sehr ausführliche Zusammenstellung von typografischen Satzregeln ist ebenfalls als PDF herunterladbar: [Solbrig, Amelie: »Zweisprachige Mikrotypografie«, Diplomarbeit, HTWK Leipzig, 2008](http://bmb.htwk-leipzig.de/de/branche/diplomarbeiten/gestaltungtypografie/zweisprachige-mikrotypografie/)

Comment: Das verlinkte Typografie-Regelwerk ist sehr hilfreich. Danke.

Comment: Hier noch ein weiterer schöner Link: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/typografie-anfuhrungszeichen.php

Comment: Schöne und ausführliche Antwort, @TehMacDawg! Erklärst Du bitte noch die Signifikanz der Zahlen (99, 66 etc)? Die ist mir nicht klar.

Comment: @elena: Diese Gepflogenheit kommt aus dem Bereich [Textsatz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_(Druck)). Die Zahlen ähneln der Form der verschiedenen Anführungszeichen und verdeutlichen, welche Zeichenform genau gemeint ist: 99 unten = **„** | 99 oben = **”** | 66 = **“**. Die Zahlenfolge funktioniert gut als Merkhilfe, z.B.: Spanischer Text: 66–99, Deutscher Text umgekehrt: 99–66, Niederländischer Text: 99–99 (echt!)

Comment: Leider sind sich die Designer von Schriftarten (fonttypes) oft nicht über die Bedeutung dieser Zeichen im Klaren. Nimm den Text "99 unten = „ | 99 oben = ” | 66 = “.", kopiere ihn in Word und formatiere in in den Schriftarten Arial, Garamond oder Times New Roman. Du wirst sehen, dass alles gut ist. Nun formatiere diesen Text, ohne an seinem Inhalt etwas zu ändern mit der Schriftart Verdana oder Courier New und sieh dir an, was aus “ (also aus 66-oben) geworden ist! Dieses Zeichen ist in diesen Schriftarten in die falsche Richtung geneigt.

Comment: Auch wenn jemand das Tag 'Typographie' unter meine Frage geklebt hat - wie mein Hinweis auf 'kursiv' auch hätte klar machen sollen ist Typographie hier nicht Thema. In den Kommentaren von mir aus...

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Jedem Schriftdesigner, der auch nur halbwegs was von seinem Fach versteht, ist die Bedeutung dieser Zeichen sehr wohl klar. Die 6699-Faustregel sagt auch nichts darüber aus, wie die dazugehörigen Zeichen in einer Schrift auszusehen haben. Solange es verschiedene öffnende und schließende Anführungszeichen gibt, ist alles ok. Siehe z.B. [erst hier](http://www.typophile.com/node/21213#comment-133619) und [dann hier](http://www.typophile.com/node/21213#comment-134067).

Comment: @Clemens: Deine beiden Beispiele beziehen sich auf die englische Sprache, wo die Zeichen 66 und 99 beide oben gesetzt werden. Das Problem ist, dass "66 oben" im Englischen am Beginn eines Zitats gesetzt wird, und dafür kann man auch ein Glyph nehmen, das aus zwei Strichen besteht, die so geneigt sind: \\. Im Deutschen ist "66 oben" aber ein Zeichen, das am Ende eines Zitats gesetzt wird, und da ist es ganz einfach falsch, die Striche so zu neigen. Die Stiche müssten in der deutschen End-Zitat-Variante so verlaufen: //. Genau das ist aber in manchen Schriftarten nicht der Fall.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Für die deutsche Sprache gilt aber das gleiche: solange es eine führende und eine schließende Glyphe gibt ist der Rest dem Schriftdesigner überlassen, auch die Neigung der Zeichen. In der Kunst (und Schriftdesign und Typographie gehören dazu) gibt es kein _müssen_. Abgesehen davon habe ich nie gesagt, dass Verdana eine schöne Schrift wäre ;)